# Jinja2 in Python will not accept yml input because values are in a list instead of dict

Tags: python, sql, list, dictionary, jinja2

right now I am using Jinja2 in Python to read yml files as input and generate sql based on the corresponding j2 templates.

Most of my ymls look like this, which work fine:

```
{
  "template": "create_view_v3.sql.j2",
  "vars": {
    "var_env_list": ["T","A"],
    "var_list": ["VALUE1","VALUE2"],
    "var_context_src": "WH"
  }
}
```

Whereby I generate the sql like this:

```
    data = yml_file["vars"]
    query = template.render(data)
```

However one of my yml's is given me some trouble.
The following yml returns this error:

> ctx = self.new_context(dict(*args, **kwargs)) ValueError: dictionary
> update sequence element #0 has length 6; 2 is required

The yml in question looks like (with 6 users instead of 2):

```
{
    "template": "create_named_user_v4.sql.j2",
    "vars": [
        { 
            "var_login_name": "user1@email.com",
            "var_user_name": "USR1",
            "var_display_name": "User 1",
            "var_user_email": "user1@email.com",
            "var_group": "PUBLIC",
            "var_sso": "sso"
        },
        { 
            "var_login_name": "user2@email.com",
            "var_user_name": "USR2",
            "var_display_name": "User 2",
            "var_user_email": "user2@email.com",
            "var_group": "PUBLIC",
            "var_sso": "sso"
        }
    ]
}
```

The j2 file starts out with:

```
{% for var_login_name, var_user_name, var_display_name, var_user_email, var_group, var_sso in j2_vars|sort  %}
```

I believe the issue is that the "vars" in this yml returns a list rather than a dict.
Is there an easy way in which I can make Jinja work on this given template?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Why the <sql> tag? I see no SQL above. Do you expect an SQL answer?

Comment: Hi @jarlh, I added the <sql> tag since Jinja2 is generating SQL, my apologies if I wasn't supposed to add this.

Comment: If you think it's a SQL related problem, you should probably show us the generated SQL.